# В чем разница между MessageContract и DataContract в WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Когда используется одно, а когда другое?
С виду эти контракты очень похожи

Comment: Пока не дали ответ, то можете почитать аналог с [английского SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118654/datacontract-vs-message-contract)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**В общих чертах:**

*Соглашения* (`Contracts`) в `WCF` предоставляют совместимость, необходимую для взаимодействия с клиентом. `DataContract` и `MessageContract` являются *структурными соглашениями* (`structural contracts`), которые дополняют друг друга и служат разным целям.

`DataContract` - это соглашение между сторонами (сервисом и клиентом), которое описывает тип данных, которым они будут обмениваться, иными словами `DataContract` используется для определения структуры данных сообщения, т.е. `DataContract` определяет какие параметры и возвращаемые типы будут *сериализованы/десериализованы* `Binary <==> XML` для обмена между сторонами.

`WCF` использует *SOAP-сообщения* для общения. `MessageContract` используется для контроля структуры тела *SOAP-сообщения* (`SOAP message body`) и сериализации данных, а так же для передачи информации в заголовках *SOAP-сообщений* (`SOAP header`).

Таким образом, использование `MessageContract` предпочтительно только тогда, когда существует необходимость контролировать "макет" вашего сообщения (*SOAP-сообщения*). Например, добавить специфичные данные в *Header SOAP-сообщения*.

---

**Итого:**

В 90% случаев, использования `DataContract` будет достаточно для достижения поставленных целей, но если же вам необходимо очень тщательно контролировать "макет" вашего *SOAP-сообщения*, то тут на помощь приходит `MessageContract`.